# Auto-increase datatype in postgres.bki file

Tags: postgresql

In Postgresql, I understand that postgres.bki file let us create a table after ./initdb automatically.
I want to created a table that has id column with auto-increase data type (like SERIAL data type in Postgresql).

In postgres.bki, SERIAL type is not acceptable.
How can I create that type?

I have refer to some other tables in postgres.bki. But it seems there is no table has column with that type.

Comment: There is no `serial` data type. I think that modifying the PostgreSQL source is an unnecessarily complicated way of creating additional tables in PostgreSQL. Why don't you run an SQL script after `initdb`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to create a table like system table for managing something that the user cannot alter or update it directly. And this table will implicitly create automatically after initdb, so I do not use SQL script.

Comment: I see. You can easily achieve that if you have the table owned by a superuser, because none of your users get superuser access.

Comment: REVOKE does magic to control access to a table

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I agree. But must the table be created manually? I mean I have to use command "CREATE TABLE ..." to create it. And if I use \d command, the table still show up?